# How do I check if an IP-address or a network is contained in other network in Bash?

Tags: bash, networking

I need to check if an IP-address or a network is contained in other network, e.g. if '10.1.2.3' is in '10.0.0.0/8' or if '10.1.2.0/24' is in '10.0.0.0/8'. Currently I use python for this, e.g.:

```
if [ $(python -c 'import ipaddress; print(ipaddress.ip_address("10.1.2.3") in ipaddress.ip_network("10.0.0.0/8"))') == "True" ]; then
    echo "10.1.2.3 is in network 10.0.0.0/8"
fi
```

Is there a more concise/efficient way to do this in Bash?

Comment: You could do this entirely in bash, but it definitely would be less concise.

Comment: Have you checked `ipcalc` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's not so concise bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

v4dec() {
        for i; do
                echo $i | {
                        IFS=./
                        read a b c d e
                        test -z "$e" && e=32
                        echo -n "$((a<<24|b<<16|c<<8|d)) $((-1<<(32-e))) "
                }
        done
}

v4test() {
        v4dec $1 $2 | {
                read addr1 mask1 addr2 mask2
                if (( (addr1&mask2) == (addr2&mask2) && mask1 >= mask2 )); then
                        echo "$1 is in network $2"
                else
                        echo "$1 is not in network $2"
                fi
        }
}

v4test 10.1.2.3 10.0.0.0/8
v4test 10.1.2.0/24 10.0.0.0/8
v4test 192.168.0.1 10.0.0.0/8
v4test 10.0.0.0/7 10.0.0.0/8
```

Output:

```
10.1.2.3 is in network 10.0.0.0/8
10.1.2.0/24 is in network 10.0.0.0/8
192.168.0.1 is not in network 10.0.0.0/8
10.0.0.0/7 is not in network 10.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: Woah. Is there any chance, you could explain how this script works?

Comment: the most elegant bit of bash i've seen in quite a while. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An awk script to do this for an ip addr in a network. I guess a little more would be needed for the network in a network part.

```
ipcalc -b 10.0.0.0/8 |awk -f check_ip.awk  ip="10.1.2.3"
ip is in range
```

script --

```
{
 if ($1 == "HostMin:") {
  split($2,add_min,".")
 } else if ($1 == "HostMax:") {
  split($2,add_max,".")
 }

} 

END{
   split(ip, ip_addr, ".")

   found = 1
   for(i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    if (ip_addr[i] < add_min[i] || ip_addr[i] > add_max[i]) {
        found = 0
        break
    }
   }            
    if (found)
     print "ip is in range"
    else
     print "ip is Not in range"

   }
```