# Check IP is in Range of Whitelist Array

Tags: shell-script, ip

```
#!/bin/bash

MAXCDN_ARRAY="108.161.176.0/20 94.46.144.0/20 146.88.128.0/20 198.232.124.0/22 23.111.8.0/22 217.22.28.0/22 64.125.76.64/27 64.125.76.96/27 64.125.78.96/27 64.125.78.192/27 64.125.78.224/27 64.125.102.32/27 64.125.102.64/27 64.125.102.96/27 94.31.27.64/27 94.31.33.128/27 94.31.33.160/27 94.31.33.192/27 94.31.56.160/27 177.54.148.0/24 185.18.207.65/26 50.31.249.224/27 50.31.251.32/28 119.81.42.192/27 119.81.104.96/28 119.81.67.8/29 119.81.0.104/30 119.81.1.144/30 27.50.77.226/32 27.50.79.130/32 119.81.131.130/32 119.81.131.131/32 216.12.211.59/32 216.12.211.60/32 37.58.110.67/32 37.58.110.68/32 158.85.206.228/32 158.85.206.231/32 174.36.204.195/32 174.36.204.196/32"

$IP = 108.161.184.123

if [ $IP in $MAXCDN_ARRAY ];
    then:
        echo "$IP is in MAXCDN range"
    else:
        echo "$IP is not in MAXCDN range"
fi
```

I have a list of IPs in `MAXCDN_ARRAY` to be used as whitelist. I want to check if a specific IP address is in range in this array.

How can I structure the code so that it can compare all IPs in the array and say the specific IP in in range of this list or not?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use shell script for this?

Comment: Thanks @Shadur. Not sure, but cant shell script detect IP value is in range by comparing numbers or strings? What do you recommend?

Comment: How "exact" do you want to have the result? What should be the output for your exampe? `IS` or `IS NOT` in the range? I am asking because in the list you have the subnetmask.

Comment: @AlBundy, Thanks. Well MaxCDN servers connect my server to retrieves files for CDN purposes. I just need to detect the IP belongs to the MaxCDN company or not with the specified array. They have tons of servers around world so checking IP in subnetmask is inevitable I suppose.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [grepcidr](http://www.pc-tools.net/unix/grepcidr/) to check if an IP address is in a list of CIDR networks.

```
#! /bin/bash

NETWORKS="108.161.176.0/20 94.46.144.0/20 146.88.128.0/20 198.232.124.0/22
          23.111.8.0/22 217.22.28.0/22 64.125.76.64/27 64.125.76.96/27
          64.125.78.96/27 64.125.78.192/27 64.125.78.224/27 64.125.102.32/27
          64.125.102.64/27 64.125.102.96/27 94.31.27.64/27 94.31.33.128/27
          94.31.33.160/27 94.31.33.192/27 94.31.56.160/27 177.54.148.0/24
          185.18.207.65/26 50.31.249.224/27 50.31.251.32/28 119.81.42.192/27
          119.81.104.96/28 119.81.67.8/29 119.81.0.104/30 119.81.1.144/30
          27.50.77.226/32 27.50.79.130/32 119.81.131.130/32 119.81.131.131/32
          216.12.211.59/32 216.12.211.60/32 37.58.110.67/32 37.58.110.68/32
          158.85.206.228/32 158.85.206.231/32 174.36.204.195/32
          174.36.204.196/32"

for IP in 108.161.184.123 108.161.176.123 192.168.0.1 172.16.21.99; do
    grepcidr "$NETWORKS" <(echo "$IP") >/dev/null && \
        echo "$IP is in MAXCDN range" || \
        echo "$IP is not in MAXCDN range"
done
```

NOTE: `grepcidr` expects the IP address(es) it is matching to be in a file, not just an argument on the command line.  That's why I had to use `<(echo "$IP")` above.

Output:

```
108.161.184.123 is in MAXCDN range
108.161.176.123 is in MAXCDN range
192.168.0.1 is not in MAXCDN range
172.16.21.99 is not in MAXCDN range
```

[`grepcidr`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/grepcidr/grepcidr.1.en.html) is available pre-packaged for several distros, including Debian:

```
Package: grepcidr
Version: 2.0-1
Description-en: Filter IP addresses matching IPv4 CIDR/network specification
 grepcidr can be used to filter a list of IP addresses against one or
 more Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR) specifications, or
 arbitrary networks specified by an address range. As with grep, there
 are options to invert matching and load patterns from a file.
 grepcidr is capable of comparing thousands or even millions of IPs
 to networks with little memory usage and in reasonable computation
 time.
 .
 grepcidr has endless uses in network software, including: mail
 filtering and processing, network security, log analysis, and many
 custom applications.
 Homepage: http://www.pc-tools.net/unix/grepcidr/
```

Otherwise, the source is available at the link above.

---

Another alternative is to write a `perl` or `python` script using one of the many libraries/modules for manipulating and checking IPv4 addresses with those languages.

For example, the `perl` module `Data::Validate::IP` has an `is_innet_ipv4($ip, $network)` function; `Net::CIDR::Lite` has a very similar `$cidr->find($ip);` method; and `Net::IPv4Addr` has an `ipv4_in_network()` function.

`python` has comparable libraries, including `ipy`, `ipaddr`, and `ipcalc`, amongst others.

Comment: thanks so much for your detailed answer. It looks great. I have CentOS 7 VPS, not sure grepcidr can be used with CentOS. I am not good at compiling but will give it a try on DigitalOcean. So it seems there is no default algorithm to check IPs by shell way, right? BTW, I will accept your answer if there is no shell way answer.

Comment: it's probably *possible* to do entirely in shell, but you'd have to write a couple of shell functions to do it, probably totalling 50-100 lines of code.   writing it in `perl` or `python` would probably be less than 10 lines of code.  check if `grepcidr` or similar tools have been packaged for centos before compiling it yourself - it's almost always better to use packages for your distro than compiling and installing in /usr/local.

Comment: @cas - It's fairly trivial to do it entirely in shell. [My solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465372/102634) below is 43 lines, including whitespace and comments. Only 24 lines of code (fewer, if readability isn't an issue).

Answer (score 12):

I realize that this is older and already has an accepted answer, but this solution utilizes a function I wrote for portability across multiple servers in an environment where `grepcidr` wasn't a standard package across all servers.

The comments should clarify just what it's doing.

```
#! /bin/bash

# Set DEBUG=1, in order to see it iterate through the calculations.
#DEBUG=1

MAXCDN_ARRAY="108.161.176.0/20 94.46.144.0/20 146.88.128.0/20 198.232.124.0/22 23.111.8.0/22 217.22.28.0/22 64.125.76.64/27 64.125.76.96/27 64.125.78.96/27 64.125.78.192/27 64.125.78.224/27 64.125.102.32/27 64.125.102.64/27 64.125.102.96/27 94.31.27.64/27 94.31.33.128/27 94.31.33.160/27 94.31.33.192/27 94.31.56.160/27 177.54.148.0/24 185.18.207.65/26 50.31.249.224/27 50.31.251.32/28 119.81.42.192/27 119.81.104.96/28 119.81.67.8/29 119.81.0.104/30 119.81.1.144/30 27.50.77.226/32 27.50.79.130/32 119.81.131.130/32 119.81.131.131/32 216.12.211.59/32 216.12.211.60/32 37.58.110.67/32 37.58.110.68/32 158.85.206.228/32 158.85.206.231/32 174.36.204.195/32 174.36.204.196/32"

IP=108.161.184.123

function in_subnet {
    # Determine whether IP address is in the specified subnet.
    #
    # Args:
    #   sub: Subnet, in CIDR notation.
    #   ip: IP address to check.
    #
    # Returns:
    #   1|0
    #
    local ip ip_a mask netmask sub sub_ip rval start end

    # Define bitmask.
    local readonly BITMASK=0xFFFFFFFF

    # Set DEBUG status if not already defined in the script.
    [[ "${DEBUG}" == "" ]] && DEBUG=0

    # Read arguments.
    IFS=/ read sub mask <<< "${1}"
    IFS=. read -a sub_ip <<< "${sub}"
    IFS=. read -a ip_a <<< "${2}"

    # Calculate netmask.
    netmask=$(($BITMASK<<$((32-$mask)) & $BITMASK))

    # Determine address range.
    start=0
    for o in "${sub_ip[@]}"
    do
        start=$(($start<<8 | $o))
    done

    start=$(($start & $netmask))
    end=$(($start | ~$netmask & $BITMASK))

    # Convert IP address to 32-bit number.
    ip=0
    for o in "${ip_a[@]}"
    do
        ip=$(($ip<<8 | $o))
    done

    # Determine if IP in range.
    (( $ip >= $start )) && (( $ip <= $end )) && rval=1 || rval=0

    (( $DEBUG )) &&
        printf "ip=0x%08X; start=0x%08X; end=0x%08X; in_subnet=%u\n" $ip $start $end $rval 1>&2

    echo "${rval}"
}

for subnet in $MAXCDN_ARRAY
do
    (( $(in_subnet $subnet $IP) )) &&
        echo "${IP} is in ${subnet}" && break
done
```

Comment: I like this answer!

Comment: Best answer. Code is much cleaner than the other answers, but can be simplified a bit:
To check if IPs are in the same subnet, simply AND them with $netmask and check for equality.

Works perfectly with Bash 4+ from 2009, probably even older versions.

Comment: @JustinSane - Dagnabbit. Why didn't I think of that? :D

Comment: Simply AND them with $netmask looks like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258869/how-do-i-check-if-an-ip-address-or-a-network-is-contained-in-other-network-in-ba

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to run this on a bunch of hosts without having to install `grepcidr` and I tried [the script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465372) by [Deacon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/102634/deacon) but it didn't work, so here's one I wrote that's confirmed working.  Hopefully someone will find this useful:

```bash
function in_subnet {
    # Determine whether IP address is in the specified subnet.
    #
    # Args:
    #   cidr_subnet: Subnet, in CIDR notation.
    #   ip_addr: IP address to check.
    #
    # Returns:
    #   0|1
    #
    local readonly cidr_subnet="${1}"
    local readonly ip_addr="${2}"
    local subnet_ip cidr_mask netmask ip_addr_subnet subnet rval

    subnet_ip=$(echo "${cidr_subnet}" | cut -d'/' -f1)
    cidr_mask=$(echo "${cidr_subnet}" | cut -d'/' -f2)

    netmask=$(( 0xFFFFFFFF << $(( 32 - ${cidr_mask} )) ))

    # Apply netmask to both the subnet IP and the given IP address 
    ip_addr_subnet=$(( netmask & $(ip_to_int ${ip_addr}) ))
    subnet=$(( netmask & $(ip_to_int ${subnet_ip}) ))

    # Subnet IPs will match if given IP address is in CIDR subnet
    [ "${ip_addr_subnet}" == "${subnet}" ] && rval=0 || rval=1

    return $rval
}

function ip_to_int {
    local readonly ip_addr="${1}"
    local ip_1 ip_2 ip_3 ip_4

    ip_1=$(echo "${ip_addr}" | cut -d'.' -f1)
    ip_2=$(echo "${ip_addr}" | cut -d'.' -f2)
    ip_3=$(echo "${ip_addr}" | cut -d'.' -f3)
    ip_4=$(echo "${ip_addr}" | cut -d'.' -f4)

    echo $(( ip_1 * 256**3 + ip_2 * 256**2 + ip_3 * 256 + ip_4 ))
}
```

Comment: when you say `I tried the script by Doug R. but it didn't work`, which answer by "Doug R." didn't work? I don't see an answer here by Doug R.

Comment: @gene_wood - I have since changed my username, he meant the solution that now shows as by Deacon.

Comment: @scottyhardy - I'm actually just now actually thoroughly reading your code for the very first time (not sure why it took me almost 4y, but what the heck). While I'm not certain why my version didn't work for you (it did for me while I was using it), yours is definitely simpler, easier to follow, and probably more bulletproof. It's closer to what I would write today if I were doing a rewrite. I wish I could give it more than one upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
# SETUP CIDR ARRAY DATA
cidrs=(10.10.10.0/24 20.20.20.0/24)
cidrarr=()
for cidr in "${cidrs[@]}"; do
    mask=$(echo $cidr | cut -d/ -f2)
    ip=$(echo $cidr | cut -d/ -f1)
    cidrdec=0;maskdec=0;p=0
    for i in {1..4}; do
        e=$((2**$((8*(4-$i)))))
        o=$(echo $ip | cut -d. -f$i)
        cidrdec=$(($cidrdec+$o*$e))
    done
    for ((i=1; i<=$mask; i++)); do
        maskdec=$(($maskdec+2**(32-$i)))
    done
    cidrarr+=($cidr)
    cidrarr+=($cidrdec)
    cidrarr+=($maskdec)
done
# END SETUP CIDR ARRAY DATA

cidrtest() {
    ipdec=0
    for i in {1..4}; do
        e=$((2**$((8*(4-$i)))))
        o=$(echo $1 | cut -d. -f$i)
        ipdec=$(($ipdec+$o*$e))
    done
    for i in ${!cidrarr[@]}; do
        [ $((i%3)) -ne 0 ] && continue
        t=${cidrarr[i+1]}
        m=${cidrarr[i+2]}
        ipm=$(($ipdec & $m))
        [[ $ipm -eq $t ]] && echo "$1 is within ${cidrarr[i]}"
    done
}

cidrtest 10.10.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved script based on `grepcidr` which displays the matching CIDR.

Script:

```bsh
echo -e "Searching...\n"; cat cidr.txt | while read NETWORK; do grepcidr "$NETWORK" ip.txt && echo -e "=> found in $NETWORK\n"; done
```

Example of result:

```bsh
Searching...

172.17.1.1
172.18.1.1
=> found in 172.16.0.0/12

192.168.50.1
=> found in 192.168.50.0/24
```