# Check IP in CIDR list with grepcidr

Tags: bash

Why this work?

```
# grepcidr 5.45.148.0 list.txt

list.txt
5.45.148.0/22
5.45.148.0/24
```

and this doesn't work?

```
# grepcidr 5.45.148.23 list.txt

list.txt
5.45.148.0/22
5.45.148.0/24
```

grepcidr 2.0 provided from CentOS7 repos

Comment: This gets stranger. Using your `list.txt`, `grepcidr 5.45.149.5/22 list.txt` returns both records, not just `5.45.148.0/22`. I don't see how 5.45.149.5 can be a member of 5.45.148.0/24, no matter how you slice it

Comment: yes, the grepcidr behaviour is strange, at least in its v.2 version. However this is the only one provided by CentOS 7 rpm repos. Still worse, I see in more distros: http://rpm.pbone.net/results_srodzaj_3_search_grepcidr.html

Comment: thanks. I have done it

Comment: @roaima, you're mis-interpreting the output.  `grepcidr` is showing you the lines of the file which contain entries that are in the same /22 as you gave it.  5.45.148.0/24 is a member of 5.45.149.5/22, not vice-versa.

Comment: @JimL. thank you. I have been wondering about this command and couldn't get any definitive detail even from its website. I do like your needles and haystack analogy. I wish the man page actually explained what was going on, and provided a few non-trivial examples

Comment: I like too the analogy of needles and haystack, easy to understand. Thank your for the good explanations. Just to point that for the utility I miss, a bash script like this from the user Deacon can be useful:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274330/check-ip-is-in-range-of-whitelist-array

Comment: please accept the correct answer if you found your answer. @Porisco

Comment: yes, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll grant that `grepcidr` may have some quirks and bugs, but much of your
surmisal is, IMO incorrect.  And to be fair, parts of this answer are also under-informed, but my intent is to point out that even v2 has some utility, if one approaches the syntax and output with a different paradigm.

I started using `grepcidr` for some firewalling scripts a few months ago, so
my understanding of it is still nascent.  But from what I have gathered,
`grepcidr` doesn't work exactly like `grep`.  In particular, my "mental map"
to date suggests that `grepcidr doesn't look for lines in the input file that
contain a string (or a CIDR spec), it looks for lines in the input file that
*ARE* contained by a CIDR spec.

To put it another way, grep looks for a needle in a haystack.  With
`grepcidr`, you give it a haystack, and grepcidr shows you all the needles
that are contained in the haystack.  That's still a bit loose, but ....
`grepcidr` looks for entries in the file that are a subset -- possibly an
improper subset -- of the command-line search spec.

Consider this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat << EOF > list.txt
5.45.148.0/22
5.45.148.0/24
5.45.149.0/24
5.45.150.0/24
5.45.151.0/24
5.45.152.0/24
5.45.151.17
5.45.151.17 5.45.151.18 5.45.151.19
5.45.151.247
5.44.15.17
5.44.1.0/24
5.44.1.15
5.44.1.5
5.44.1.5/32
EOF

grepcidr -V

j=0

echo $((++j)): "Lines containing entries within 5.45.151.17 (/32)"
grepcidr 5.45.151.17 list.txt

echo $((++j)): "Lines containing entries in the same /24 as 5.45.151.17"
grepcidr 5.45.151.17/24 list.txt

echo $((++j)): "Lines that have no entries within 5.45.0.0/16"
grepcidr -v 5.45.0.0/16 list.txt

echo $((++j)): "Lines with entries within 5.45.151.17/31"
grepcidr 5.45.151.17/31 list.txt
```

Output:

```
grepcidr 2.0
Copyright (C) 2004 - 2014  Jem E. Berkes <jem@berkes.ca>

1: Lines containing entries within 5.45.151.17 (/32)
5.45.151.17
5.45.151.17 5.45.151.18 5.45.151.19
2: Lines containing entries in the same /24 as 5.45.151.17
5.45.151.0/24
5.45.151.17
5.45.151.17 5.45.151.18 5.45.151.19
5.45.151.247
3: Lines that have no entries within 5.45.0.0/16
5.44.15.17
5.44.1.0/24
5.44.1.15
5.44.1.5
5.44.1.5/32
4: Lines with entries within 5.45.151.17/31
5.45.151.17
5.45.151.17 5.45.151.18 5.45.151.19
```

To your specific example, you asked `grepcidr`, "Does this specific IP appear as a /32 listed in this file?" and no, it doesn't.  If you instead ask, does the /24 that this IP is in appear in this file, then yes, it does, in two places:

```
# grepcidr 5.45.148.23 list.txt
# grepcidr 5.45.148.23/24 list.txt
5.45.148.0/22
5.45.148.0/24
```

So yes, V3 may well be an improvement over V2, and yes, it will be a good day when so many Unix and Linux distros update their package repos, but that's not to say that V2 is useless.  One just has to be careful about what conclusions one draws from the output.

## UPDATE

After adding the new `-s` flag to permit "sloppy" CIDR specs, it appears the same.  Highly likely that my test cases are not exhaustive.

```
1: Lines containing entries within 5.45.151.17 (/32)
5.45.151.17
5.45.151.17 5.45.151.18 5.45.151.19
2: Lines containing entries in the same /24 as 5.45.151.17
5.45.151.0/24
5.45.151.17
5.45.151.17 5.45.151.18 5.45.151.19
5.45.151.247
3: Lines that have no entries within 5.45.0.0/16
5.44.15.17
5.44.1.0/24
5.44.1.15
5.44.1.5
5.44.1.5/32
4: Lines with entries within 5.45.151.17/31
5.45.151.17
5.45.151.17 5.45.151.18 5.45.151.19
```

FWIW, your particular test case behavior is unchanged in V3:

```
# grepcidr -V
grepcidr 3.0
Parts copyright (C) 2004, 2005  Jem E. Berkes <jberkes@pc-tools.net>

# grepcidr 5.45.148.23 list.txt
```

... although the solution does indeed appear to be in @RasoolZiafaty's suggestion to use the `-D` flag:

```
# grepcidr -D 5.45.148.23 list.txt
5.45.148.0/22
5.45.148.0/24
```

One continuing puzzlement I have is why IP ranges are not equivalent to explicitly-listed IPs:

```
# cat input.txt 
5.45.148.3 5.45.148.4 5.45.148.5
5.45.148.3-5.45.148.5
# grepcidr -D 5.45.148.4 input.txt 
5.45.148.3 5.45.148.4 5.45.148.5
```

The current behavior seems to be that specific IPs on the command line only match file lines if the file line references that IP as a start- or endpoint.  E.g. `5.45.148.4` is found on only one line, whereas `5.45.148.3` or `5.45.148.5` match on two lines.

Comment: thanks. That's finally clarifying.  Then grepcidr seem to be focused in checking if a list of subsets and ips belongs to the given input which logically would be a cdir. Besides the lack of  explanations in the README section, what more confused me is the possibility to check one ip.  If the intention is to check one ip, a forced parameter and explanations would be needed. I'm sorry if the views were unfair. I had headaches with grepcidr to parse lists from users who were rejected by the firewall despite the cdir ranges were present. Some were allowed and others rejected despite right cdir's.

Answer (score 3):

try use -D in your command

```
grepcidr -D 5.45.148.3 list.txt
```

> -D    Parse CIDR ranges in input and match if a search term matches any part of the range.

Comment: What version are you using?. I get error with grecidr 2.0, the only available form CentOS 7.0 rpm Repos. Thanks!

    # grepcidr -D 5.45.148.3 lista.txt
    grepcidr: invalid option -- 'D'
    Usage:
            grepcidr [-V] [-cisvx] PATTERN [FILE...]
            grepcidr [-V] [-cisvx] [-e PATTERN | -f PATFILE] [FILE...]

Comment: i have used this github repo very easy to build and install https://github.com/ryantig/grepcidr, and new version is https://github.com/jrlevine/grepcidr3

Comment: you are right, the v3 version seems to work fine

Answer (score 2):

`grepcidr` searches for IP addresses that may be in a CIDR network.  You are trying to use it in the other direction (searching for CIDR networks that may contain a given IP address).

```sh
function reversegrepcidr() { 
  grep "$( 
    while read; do 
      echo $1 | grepcidr "$REPLY" &>/dev/null && echo $REPLY
    done < <( grep -Eo "[^^\"][0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]{1,2}" "$2" )
   )" "$2"; 
}
```

This function searches for anything that looks like a CIDR network, and for each one uses `grepcidr` to see if its first argument is in that network, and if it is, prints that network.

Warning: this may not work with all versions of `grep`, and was only lightly tested with GNU `grep` 3.4, and `grepcidr` 2.0.