# How do I check if an IP-address or a network is contained in other network in BusyBox shell?

Tags: shell-script, busybox

A BusyBox shell script has a list of IPs to be used as whitelist for a firewall `ipset` list. The whitelist may contain non routable IP's to be whitelisted. On the other hand [firehol_level1](http://iplists.firehol.org/) list ([fullbogons](http://iplists.firehol.org/?ipset=fullbogons#)) does contain rfc1918 non routable CIDRs.

My first attempt is to use `iprange` to exclude whitelist matching CIDR's
`iprange --common net.txt whitelist.txt` and the file order exchanged `iprange --common whitelist.txt net.txt` will always output the IP, never the CIDR (netblock).

In case a whitelist IP matches a netblock, the netblock should be removed from (`ipset`) list.

User yaegashi has a nice [bash is ipv4/cidr (not) in network script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258926/17560):

```
#!/bin/bash

v4dec() {
        for i; do
                echo $i | {
                        IFS=./
                        read a b c d e
                        test -z "$e" && e=32
                        echo -n "$((a<<24|b<<16|c<<8|d)) $((-1<<(32-e))) "
                }
        done
}

v4test() {
        v4dec $1 $2 | {
                read addr1 mask1 addr2 mask2
                if (( (addr1&mask2) == (addr2&mask2) && mask1 >= mask2 )); then
                        echo "$1 is in network $2"
                else
                        echo "$1 is not in network $2"
                fi
        }
}
```

However that bash script **does not run on busybox shell**. I have modified that to run on busybox shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

v4dec() {
        for i; do
                echo $i | {
                        IFS=./
                        read a b c d e
                        test -z "$e" && e=32
                        echo -n "$((a<<24|b<<16|c<<8|d)) $((-1<<(32-e))) "
                }
        done
}

v4dec $1 $2 | {
  read addr1 mask1 addr2 mask2
    if [ $(($addr1&$mask2)) -eq $(($addr2&$mask2)) ] && [ $mask1 -ge $mask2 ]; then
      echo "$1 is in network $2"
    else
      echo "$1 is not in network $2"
    fi
}
```

Is my BusyBox (tested with v1.24.2) shell script translation of yaegashi v4test doing the same thing, or did I make mistakes?

Or is there a better way to remove CIDR entries from an ipset hash:net list that match a list of IPv4 addresses on limited hardware (no Perl/Python/etcetera)?

Comment: Is it not possible to allow the specific IP **first**, then deny the rest of the CIDR **later**, so that opening a hole for, say,10.0.0.5 doesn't open your system up to the entire 10.0.0.0/8 CIDR?  Allow the one, then deny the many.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with `iprange` is that the whitelisted IPs need to be written in CIDR format.

Suffix the IP with `/20`and or `/24` improves the netblock matching:

```
$ cat net-optim.txt
1.10.16.0/20

$ cat whitelist.txt
1.10.16.1/20
1.10.16.1/24

$ iprange --common net-optim.txt whitelist.txt
1.10.16.0/20
```

Combining `iprange --exclude` with `--ipset-reduce 20`fails. Giving up using `iprange` and will fall back to removing 192.168.0.* using `grep`.